# Previous year not same when run in jasper

Tags: node.js, jasper-reports

The problem is when i try make previous year in console is works like charm!.But when i tried in jasper the output not same like in console.

console :

[image]

Jasper :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you also used `java.util.Date` at the console? Or did you use a sql `Date` class?

Comment: im using new Date() in console also with jasper, still same the problem

Comment: Have you tried `new java.util.Date` at the console, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `java.util.Date` because it is deprecated
2. If you use it, see the documentation:

> ```
> /**
>  * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it so that
>  * it represents midnight, local time, at the beginning of the day
>  * specified by the <code>year</code>, <code>month</code>, and
>  * <code>date</code> arguments.
>  *
>  * @param   year    the year minus 1900.
>  * @param   month   the month between 0-11.
>  * @param   date    the day of the month between 1-31.
>  * @see     java.util.Calendar
>  * @deprecated As of JDK version 1.1,
>  * replaced by <code>Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date)</code>
>  * or <code>GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date)</code>.
>  */
> @Deprecated
> public Date(int year, int month, int date) {
>     this(year, month, date, 0, 0, 0);
> }
> ```

and observe that you need to provide:

- the year minus 1900

**Java is not JavaScript**! 
Every language has its own implementation.

If you want to get the same result, you can use:

```
new java.util.Date(2015-1900, 0, 0)
```

Even if it's not good to use a date that is not in the specified interval (1-31), you can do that trick.